# Future.wait() not catching exceptions (Dart)

Tags: exception, flutter, dart

In my Flutter app I'd like to make multiple network calls simultaneously and then do something when they all have finished. For this I use `Future.wait()`, which does what I want. However when a call fails it throws an exception, which is somehow not caught in the exception handler (i.e. uncaught exception).

When I do `await _fetchSomeData()` separately (outside `Future.wait()`) the exception does get called by the exception handler as expected.

```
  Future<bool> someMethod() async {

    try {
      var results = await Future.wait([
        _fetchSomeData(),
        _fetchSomeOtherData()
      ]);
      //do some stuf when both have finished...
      return true;
    }
    on Exception catch(e) {
      //does not get triggered somehow...
      _handleError(e);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

What do I need to do to catch the exceptions while using `Future.wait()`?

Update:

I have narrowed down the issue. Turns out if you use another await statement in the method that is called by the `Future.wait()` it causes the issue. Here an example:

```
  void _futureWaitTest() async {

    try {
      //await _someMethod(); //using this does not cause an uncaught exception, but the line below does
      await Future.wait([ _someMethod(), ]);
    }
    on Exception catch(e) {
      print(e);
    } 
  }

  Future<bool> _someMethod() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 0), () => print('wait')); //removing this prevents the uncaught exception
    throw Exception('some exception');
  }
```

So if you either remove the await line from `_someMethod()` or if you just call `_someMethod()` outside of `Future.wait()` will prevent the uncaught exception. This is most unfortunate of course, I need await for an http call... some bug in Dart?

I have the Uncaught Exceptions breakpoints enabled. If I turn this off the issue seems to be gone. Perhaps it's an issue with the debugger. I am using Visual Studio Code and the latest flutter.

Comment: Maybe you are handling those exceptions in one of those methods (_fetchSomeData or _fetchSomeOtherData) and are not re-throwing the exception to be handled above those methods.

Comment: this answer might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/16022953/4465386

Comment: `try {
var result = await Future.wait([
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => 'first'),
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => 'second'),
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () => throw Exception('bad things happened')),
]);
print('result: $result');
} on Exception catch(e) {
print('error: [$e]');
}` what do you see on the logs?

Comment: Yes that works, I've narrowed down the issue. I'm updating my post.

Comment: Please check the updated information in my opening post. Can you reproduce the issue now?

Comment: with or without `await Future.delayed(...)` inside `_someMethod` method it works just fine: `error: [...]` is printed

Comment: Do you have the Uncaught Exceptions breakpoints enabled? Otherwise the catch does get triggered here too. Maybe it's an issue with the debugger. I'm using Visual Studio with the latest Flutter.

Comment: i am just running your code and `on Exception catch(e) { ...` gets executed

Comment: I know but do you have Uncaught Exceptions breakpoints checked or not? It's on the bottom left in the Debug tab of VS.

Comment: i dont use any debug sessions: i just run it via `flutter -v run ...`

Comment: I have previously stated that the issue only occurs while debugging using uncaught exception breakpoints, so if you try to replicate please do this too.

Answer (score 2):

> What do I need to do to catch the exceptions while using Future.wait()?

What I found out when I used the same code as you the code inside of each procedure which is used in `Future.wait()` must be wrapped with `try/catch` and on `catch` must return `Future.error()`. Also `eagerError` must be set to `true`.

```
try {
  await Future.wait([proc1, ...], eagerError: true);
} on catch(e) {
  print('error: $e')
}

/// Proc 1
Future<void> proc1() async {
  try {
    final result = await func();
  } on SomeException catch(e) {
    return Future.error('proc 1 error: $');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit mislead by the `Future.wait()` naming. `Future.wait()` returns another future that will have a `List` of elements returned by each future when it completes with success.

Now since the `Future.wait()` is still a future. You can handle it in two ways:

1. Using `await` with `try catch`.
2. Using `onError` callback.

Tis will be something like

```
Future.wait([futureOne, futureTwo])
.then((listOfValues) {
    print("ALL GOOD")
 }, 
 onError: (error) { print("Something is not ok") }
```

Comment: I've tried both of those things already, you can see me using try catch in my example.

Comment: @Janneman I didn't see where you've used the ```onError``` callback.

Comment: I tried that too, but I used the try/catch approach in my example. I just updated my initial post with an update with some more information.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass exception to actual try catch part.
see modified implementation
onError will catch exception thrown from awaited Futures.

```
Future<bool> someMethod() async {

    try {
      var results = await Future.wait([
        _fetchSomeData(),
        _fetchSomeOtherData()
      ])then((value) => {}
       ,onError: (ex) => throw ex)
      .catchError((ex) => throw ex);
      //do some stuf when both have finished...
      return true;
    }catch(e) {
      _handleError(e);
      return false;
    }
  }
```